# Stop jquery scroll at fixed pixels above the target element

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I currently use this function to scroll smooth (https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo) to the target hash in the same page with Bootstrap.

```
$('.navbar .destScroll').bind('click', 'ul li a', function(event) {
    $.scrollTo(event.target.hash, 500);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Since there is a fixed 80px menu at the top of the page, I want the scroll to stop 80px above the target hash.

Please help.

Comment: Simple: try: `$("body").animate({scrollTop:""+$(event.target).offset().top+""}, 500);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using my scrollTo code, which is great - https://gist.github.com/yairEO/7030050

you can use it like this:

```
// there are 3 parameters: 
// jumpIn -  in which container to scroll (default body/html)
// quick - jump with timed animation or not (default with)
// offset - destination offset from target
$('#there').scrollToPos(null, null, -200);
```

In the above example, the window will scroll to the position of the `#there` element, with a top offset of `-200`

---

Another way to directly bind a click in one place that leads to another is by using links which has an `data-scrollTo` attribute which is a selector to an element to jump to:

```
<a data-scrollTo='#there'>go there</a>
```

Comment: Thanks vsync. It is what I wanted. Anyways, in my case since there are many targets to scroll to, I modified your code to $(event.target.hash).scrollToPos(null, null, -80); and it works perfect. Thanks again!